# How can i solve this regular expression, Python?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to construct a reg expression pattern for the following string, and use Python to extract:

```
str = "hello w0rld how 34 ar3 44 you\n welcome 200 stack000verflow\n"
```

What I want to do is extract the **independent** number values and add them which should be 278. A prelimenary python code is:

```
import re
x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', str)
```

The problem with the above code is that numbers within a char substring like 'ar3' would show up. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
s = re.findall(r"\s\d+\s", a)  # \s matches blank spaces before and after the number.
print (sum(map(int, s)))       # print sum of all
```

`\d+` matches all digits. This gives the exact expected output.

```
278
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something simpler like this?:

```
str = "hello w0rld how 34 ar3 44 you\n welcome 200 stack000verflow\n"
print sum([int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()])
# 278
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
x = re.findall('\s([0-9]+)\s', str)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a partial match
use this:
`'^[0-9]*$'`

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted so far only work (if at all) for numbers that are preceded and followed by whitespace. They will fail if a number occurs at the very start or end of the string, or if a number appears at the end of a sentence, for example. This can be avoided using [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
s = "100 bottles of beer on the wall (ignore the 1000s!), now 99, now only 98"
s = re.findall(r"\b\d+\b", a)  # \b matches at the start/end of an alphanumeric sequence
print(sum(map(int, s)))
```

Result: `297`